# Как запустить html video по окончанию загрузки?

Tags: javascript, вёрстка, api, видео, веб-программирование

Мне нужно запустить видео на странице после его полной загрузки. Я нашел такой вариант:

```
vid.addEventListener('progress', function() {
   var loadedPercentage = vid.buffered.end(0) / vid.duration;
   if(loadedPercentage > 1){
      start()
   } else {
      vid.currentTime=vid.buffered.end(0);
   }
});
```

Выдает ошибку:

> Uncaught IndexSizeError: Failed to execute 'end' on 'TimeRanges': The
>   index provided (0) is greater than or equal to the maximum bound (0).

Еще пробовал другой вариант (var loadedPercentage = 100*(vid.buffered.end(0))/vid.duration;) - аналогичная ошибка.

Как правильно?

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка говорит о том что ещё ни один "участок" видео не загружен.

Попробуйте так:

```
vid.addEventListener('progress', function() {
   if( vid.buffered.length === 0 ){
      vid.load();
      return ;
   }

   var loadedPercentage = vid.buffered.end(0) / vid.duration;
   if(loadedPercentage > 1){
      start()
   } else {
      vid.currentTime=vid.buffered.end(0);
   }
});
```

Comment: поправил код, забыл return

Comment: Спасибо за Ваш ответ! Такой вариант не работает,  после vid.currentTime=vid.buffered.end(0); не происходит загрузка следующего отрезка. Начинает работать после добавления под vid.currentTime=vid.buffered.end(0); vid.play(); vid.pause();, но ругается... в консоле про диапазон.